# Python, plotting curve into image from pixels

Tags: image, opencv, plot, pixel

I need help, I have a matrix of pixels of values 0 to 255 and I need to plot them into image with plane curve.
Into this image I need to put a specific curve.

For example, I have a curve x=10+cos(t), y=10+sin(t) and a matrix of pixels m[i][j]. I need to show both in one image, looking like that:

[image: picture]

I know I might need opencv, it's not problem, but I can't find myself writing the code.

Comment: you tagged `OpenCV` so I'm assuming you are prepared to *use* the library. if you refuse to use the library, say so. "I can't find myself writing the code." sounds like you want others to write your code for you. you should clarify. that sounds like you misunderstand the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing a circle.

If you need to draw a circle, use the `cv::circle` drawing call.

API docs: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html

If you need an ellipse, use the `ellipse` drawing call.

If you need to draw arbitrary `polylines`/`drawContours`, calculate the list of points and then use either of these calls.

[OpenCV has a `Plot2D` class in the `opencv_contrib` repository/part of the modules](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d0/d1e/classcv_1_1plot_1_1Plot2d.html). That's not parametric plot though.

Comment: The whole curve is parametrically expressed as linear combination of base functions: c+sum_i^k (alpha_i*(i*sin(t)))+sum_i^k (beta_i*(cos(t))), but it's the problem to plot this curve, the problem is how to plot this curve into one image with pixels which value is described by matrix.

Comment: great, so follow the part of my answer that says to generate the points of the contour, then use those drawing calls. -- what you describe isn't a "linear combination", it's a parametric curve. -- you tagged `OpenCV` so I'm assuming you are prepared to *use* the library.